# Javascript session refresh

Tags: node.js, ajax, session, express

I am new to javascript and am working on an application, where I have multiple tabs on my page. On click on second tab I am making an ajax call to fetch some data which I want to update in my session.

During page load I have the username in my session:

```
app.get('/home',function(req,res){  
    res.render('home',{
        layout:false,
        session: req.session
    }); 
});
```

With the above code I am able to load my home page and able to access the session from the request object, which at the moment only has the username. Onclick of 2nd tab I want to add another property " friends ".

In my controller I am writing

```
req.session.friends =  "saurabh";
```

but the same is not getting reflected on my page, because the page is not getting reloaded.

Please suggest.

Comment: look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp, I have a page similar to this, if you make a change on first tab, a corresponding change is there on the second tab.If possible, please help me with the code snippet

Comment: The link in your comment is a page about updating content on a single page using Javascript and the DOM. It has nothing to do with AJAX, or sessions, or any server-side code. It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: On page load, there is an ajax call, which fetches values from the DB. This fetch is via a server-side controller. I want to use the result on my ejs page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a workaround, as there is no direct solution.

1. I am making an Ajax call, which hits a controller and there by the DB to fetch some result.
2. From the Controller I am using res.end(data) // data is the response I need to be sent to UI
3. in Ajax success, I am generating the HTML and passing the values as and where required.

Please suggest a better alternate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have two browser windows or tabs open to a page in your application, and to have window A updated when you make a change in window B.

Assuming that's correct, a simple change to the session is not going to do it. You need some mechanism to notify window A that something has changed on the server when a change is made in window B. It will look something like this:

```
    Server        Window A        Window B
       |             |               |
       |             |             user clicks
       |<----------- | --------------|
       |   message sent to server    |
       |             |               |
    state change     |               |
    on server        |               |
       |             |               |
       |------------>|               |
       | message sent to window A    |
       |             |               |
       |          change in          |
       |          window A           |
       |             |               |
```

It sounds like you have the first part down - the message sent to the server from Window B. You mention an AJAX call to submit the request. That will work just fine.

Now you need the second part, the message to Window B. There are a couple of different ways to do this:

1. Window B can poll the server for changes, making AJAX requests every couple of seconds to ask if the state has changed.
2. Use Websockets to set up a persistent connection between the client & server. The server can then use the connection to "push" a message to the client whenever it needs to.